# Better strategy to drop ALL duplicates from pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Does anyone know a better strategy how to drop `ALL` duplicates from `pandas.DataFrame`??

I am aware of `df.drop_duplicates()`, see example below:

```
In [340]: import pandas as pd, string, random

In [341]: a = [''.join([random.choice(string.ascii_letters+string.digits) for _ in range(4)]) for _ in range(5)]

In [342]: b = [''.join([random.choice(string.digits) for _ in range(4)]) for i in range(5)]

In [343]: df1 = pd.DataFrame([a,b],index=list('ab')).T

In [344]: df1 = df1.append(df1.loc[1:3,:])

In [345]: df1.index = range(len(df1))

In [346]: df1 = df1.append(df1.loc[1:3,:])

In [347]: df1
Out[347]: 
      a     b
0  r4fb  4179
1  sv5e  8092
2  Oyeh  8788
3  fAdu  4018
4  PxKX  2818
5  sv5e  8092
6  Oyeh  8788
7  fAdu  4018
1  sv5e  8092
2  Oyeh  8788
3  fAdu  4018

In [348]: df1.drop_duplicates()
Out[348]: 
      a     b
0  r4fb  4179
1  sv5e  8092
2  Oyeh  8788
3  fAdu  4018
4  PxKX  2818
```

Note that this does not remove `ALL` duplicates, that is it removes every next non unique row, however leaves original row intact...

My current strategy and desired result is as follows:

```
In [349]: same_first = df1.duplicated(subset=['a','b'])

In [350]: same_last = df1.duplicated(subset=['a','b'], take_last=True)

In [351]: rm_lst = ~(same_first|same_last)

In [352]: df1[rm_lst]
Out[352]: 
      a     b
0  r4fb  4179
4  PxKX  2818
```

Note that now only truly `unique` rows are untouched.

Is there a better way to get same results, maybe oneliner that I've missed?

Thank you.

Comment: So you only want to drop where both a and b are duplicates, is it true that where there are duplicates in 'a' there is also a duplicate in 'b'?

Comment: I'm just trying to replicate behavior of the `drop_duplicates`, except that original row should also be dropped. Sometimes both columns may contain same data, othertimes not.

Comment: I think my answer should handle this as it deals with both columns separately

Comment: I can't accept your answer as it does seem more complicated, so by no means I wouldn't call it "a better strategy". Also it seems it will cost more processing power as in *your example* you filters column in **6 steps**: `value_counts() -> value_counts() == 1 -> df1.__getitem__() -> index -> isin() -> df1.__getitem__()`, and it's just for one column.

Comment: My *original strategy* does it in just **4 steps**: `duplicated() -> duplicated() -> comparison -> df1.__getitem__()`, and it includes any number of columns, also I can write as one liner too: `df1[~(df1.duplicated(subset=['a','b'])|df1.duplicated(subset=['a','b'], take_last=True))]`. Though thank you for comprehensive explanation of alternative method.

Comment: I agree it shows an alternative method but it's possibly clearer whilst yours requires to understand the result of the calls to `duplicated` calls and the result of the `OR`ing and then negation of this set. You should only accept answers that meet your requirements not just because it's the only answer or that produces the desired output, I was hoping someone else would suggest an alternative answer out of interest

Answer (score 1):

This does it in a one liner but is not so readable, basically it tests where the value counts for each column is equal to 1, filters the resultant list out and uses the index as a boolean indec:

```
In [260]:

df1[df1.a.isin((df1.a.value_counts()[df1.a.value_counts() == 1]).index) & (df1.b.isin((df1.b.value_counts()[df1.b.value_counts() == 1]).index))]
Out[260]:
      a     b
0  mlmv  3869
4  LPNz  4109
```

Breaking this down will show what is happening statement by statement:

```
In [261]:
# gengerate a series of the value counts
df1.a.value_counts()

Out[261]:
qPyr    3
ms7I    3
aOuL    3
LPNz    1
mlmv    1
dtype: int64

In [262]:
# we are only interested in the ones that have a unique value, this generates a boolean index we can use to index into the above series
df1.a.value_counts()[df1.a.value_counts() == 1]

Out[262]:
LPNz    1
mlmv    1
dtype: int64

In [264]:
# now use isin on the the result above, but we compare the values against the index of the result above
df1.a.isin((df1.a.value_counts()[df1.a.value_counts() == 1]).index)
Out[264]:
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
1    False
2    False
3    False
Name: a, dtype: bool
```

Comment: Thank you for the efforts. Please correct me if I'm wrong, it seems that your `(df1.a.value_counts()[df1.a.value_counts() == 1]).index) & (df1.b.isin((df1.b.value_counts()[df1.b.value_counts() == 1]).index)` does exactly the same job like my original `rm_lst = ~(same_first|same_last)` but in a lot more complicated matters?

Comment: @Narūnas yes and it looks more complicated, it's just another method but it is a bit more explicit as you are looking for unique values which `df1.a.value_counts() == 1` gives you